# correct way to include cppitertools in cmake mono repository

Tags: c++, cmake

In order to use [`cppitertools` package](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools) in my monorepository I downloaded the source files and moved them to `include` folder of my project. In the root `CmakeLists.txt` I wrote the following instructions:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(boost_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(include/fmt-7.1.3 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(include/cppitertools-2.1 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_subdirectory(itertools)
```

The content of `itertools\CmakeLists.txt` is:

```
add_executable(itertools itertools.cpp)
target_link_libraries(itertools PRIVATE cppitertools::cppitertools fmt::fmt)
```

But I have to write in a `itertools\itertools.cpp`:

```
#include <enumerate.hpp> // <<<---- how to reach #include <cppitertools/enumerate.hpp> instead??
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <string>
int main(){
    const std::string const_string("hello");
    for (auto&&[i, c] : iter::enumerate(const_string)) {
        fmt::print("({}, {}); ", i, c);
    }
}
```

**NB**: The `cppitertools_INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR` doesn't set.

Comment: 1. Create `cppitertools` folder. 2. Copy the header into the folder. 3. Add this folder to include paths.

Comment: Remove the version part from `cppitertools-2.1` and include the upper-level folder `include`, I also suggest renaming the `include` folder to something like `3rdparty`

Comment: While [README](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/README.md) contains include examples `#include <cppitertools/itertools.hpp>` and `#include <cppitertools/enumerate.hpp>`,  include directories for both build and install trees of the `cppitertools` project are configured for **omit** `cppitertools` component in `#include <>` directive: in the build tree the directory `cppitertools` even doesn't exist. So, I would assume that using `#include <enumerate.hpp>` is a correct way.